# Why isn't np.ndarray a valid type?

Tags: python, numpy, typing, mypy

I have `Vector = np.ndarray`, but MyPy later on gives me the error `Variable "main.Vector" is not valid as a type [valid-type]`.

Why?

[This issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7052) seems to be the closest, though I did not understand the explanation. [This issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7866) also seems related.

Complete code for reference:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List, Union

Vector = np.ndarray
VectorLike = Union[List[float], Vector]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Is that the entire error message?

Comment: I'm also getting a "No library stub found" for `numpy`, which may also be part of the problem.

Comment: I haven't kept close tabs on this, but `typing` and `mypy` in the past were not `numpy` aware; or conversely `numpy` has not implemented any `typing` functionality.

Comment: Because the `numpy` library doesn't provide any type hints. Run `pip install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs` to add the stubs.